# Angular 2 - cancel all route resolvers when router link is clicked

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

I use Resolver to pre-fetch data for routed component. The resolver loads data from server asynchronously, ie returns an Observable.

When user clicks on another router link (or when navigateByUrl is called for any other reason), router doesn't do anything and still waits for the Observable. The last event in console is "ResolveStart".

1. Is this how Router is supposed to work? Shouldn't it just cancel the routing and proceed to the new URL?
2. I could make the Resolver throw an exception when the link is clicked (by merging another Observable), but it seems redundant to do this for every link and resolver, is there an easier solution?